# mysqlimport - Import CSV File in MS Windows XAMPP emvironment

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I am trying to import a CSV file from to a mysql database from the command line. This will be later incorporated into a Windows batch file.

```
mysqlimport -u user -puserpw --columns=ID,CID,Alerted --fields-terminated-by=',' --local School Customer.csv
```

All the data loads into the first column in the Customer table.
I want to correctly import data from the CSV to the appropriate column.

CSV Data format:

```
ID,CID,Alerted
1,CS,N
2,CS,N
3,CS,N
```

I would like to use mysqlimport since this will be easier to add to a Windows batch file.
How can I do this please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to enclose the values in double quotes "

```
mysqlimport -u user -puserpw --columns=ID,CID,Alerted  --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by="," --lines-terminated-by="\n" --local School Customer.csv
```

That fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have to add -**-lines-terminated-by='\n'** with *mysqlimport*. I run a quick test here and worked.

```
mysqlimport --local --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=',' --lines-terminated-by='\n' db_name table_name.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the complete description for importing the csv file like :

fields terminated by ','
 enclosed by '"'
 lines terminated by '\n'

Thanks