# Optimizations for MySQL Data Import

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench

So far every time I have done a data load, it was almost always on enterprise grade hardware and so I guess I never realized 3.4 million records is big. Now to the question...

I have a local MySQL server on Windows 7, 64 bit, 4 GB RAM machine. I am importing a csv through standard 'Import into Table' functionality that is shipped with the Developer package.

My data has around 3,422,000 rows and 18 columns. 3 Columns of type double and rest is all text. Size of cvs file is about 500 MB

Both data source (CSV) and destination (MySQL) are on the same machine so I guess no network bottle neck.

It took almost 7 hours to load 200,000 records. By this speed it might take me 4 days to load entire data. Given the widespread popularity of MySQL I think there has to be a better way to make data load faster.

I have data only in CSV format and the rudimentary way I can think of is to split it into different blocks and try loading it.

Can you please suggest what optimizations can I do to speed up ?

Comment: Refer to this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002443/mysqlimport-import-csv-file-in-ms-windows-xampp-emvironment). You should  have your data imported within minutes. As for *why* it's so slow - well, you have a mechanical hard drive. They have very low amount of I/Os available, yours is probably around 300 IOPS. MySQL runs every query in autocommit mode, which translated to human language means that each row = 1 hard drive I/O. You are I/O constrained. Usual remedy is to have many inserts shoved to the HDD within 1 I/O. mysqlimport will happily do it for you.

Comment: Okay. Let me try it. Thanks N.B.

Comment: Try import to a temp table without any index first.

Comment: @Tim3880 - I believe you're trying to help, but what you're suggesting won't make anything work faster. Being I/O constrained is not "cured" by not indexing and importing into temp table. Creating the table and using mysqlimport will be fast enough.

Comment: If his table is heavily indexed, importing large data can be very different.

Comment: @Tim3880 - do you know what I/O bound is, how to calculate optimum size of a transaction based on the bandwith of the hard drive and maximum number of IOPS? Do you *understand* why many (stupid) tutorials online suggest not to index while doing inserts? Do you realize that indexing has to happen at some point? Do you realize what exactly is expensive when indexing and are you able to calculate what the penalty will be given the table structure mentioned by the OP? If the answers to my questions are no, even one of them, I suggest to find out the answers before suggesting dropping the indexes.